High latency in FastAPI service deployed in GCP
I am running a fastapi microservice in GCP K8s cluster. I am running 4 pods with the ability to scale upto 10 pods. We are using kong API gateway which is responsible for routing the requests.
We are doing some load testing and I see high latency (99th percentile) when running concurrent requests for 300-500 users.

p99 for 100 concurrent users - 700ms
p99 for 300 concurrent users - 11s
p99 for 500 concurrent users - 21s

The API makes 3 separate DB read calls to three different tables. All of the tables have very few records (<1k)
DB configuration

tier - "db-g1-small"
SSD Storage - 10GB
1 vCPU
Memory - 1.7GB

In terms of the business logic, all it does is simple calculation over the fetched records (< 15) and returns the response
I am struggling to understand the huge rise in latency between 100-300 users.
I am using locust to test the performance with 300 concurrent users, ramping up 1 user/second for 30 mins. Total requests it is able to serve is 83k with 43 requests/s

The average CPU usage stays under 60 and the pods scale as they need, the memory usage is staying well below 20%.
We use postgres via Cloud SQL in GCP. Active connections are also staying below 100 (max connections 200) and CPU utilization is at worse 60%
We have also used fastapi's autoinstrumentation to capture request/response traces and to visualize the latency in datadog. The part I am struggling to understand is why http send span is taking longer. The spans related to business logic finishes in reasonable time. See image below

I am running the app with 4 uvicorn workers (not using Gunicorn)
#! /usr/bin/env bash  

exec uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --workers 4

In short what is happening

From logs, we are seeing all the business logic execution is taking place in few milliseconds.
However, we are seeing from traces that  the part of sending the response back is taking too much time, sometimes around 20 secs


My guess is the problem is related to the database (too small). What are the latencies for database queries? Terms like number of users are not useful because you have not defined the number and frequency of requests a user makes. Almost certainly you have resource starvation. Your goal before posting a question is to figure out which resource, and then provide details on that resource.

After your last edit: You included a screenshot about requests. A request means nothing to us because you have not defined what a request does in your implementation and its requirements. Does a request generate one disk I/O (VM instance and database instance) or 100 requests? You must figure out the bottleneck first and then post a question.

Make sure you understand details like persistent disk performance. Performance is related to disk size: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance That will affect both your VM instances and the Cloud SQL database.

You are using an SSD disk of 10 GB. That will not support hundreds of simultaneous users. You are using Cloud SQL db-g1-small. I would only use that small of an instance size for testing and small sites. The configuration you deployed is too small for anything serious.

In addition to upgrading your database configuration as @John Hanley suggested, you can also consider adding more uvicorn workers.
The recommended number of workers is (2 x $num_cores) +1 [1][2].
[1]. how many uvicorn workers do I have to have in production?
[2]. https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#how-many-workers
